# How to add whitespace between two elements in razor (Blazor) file?

Tags: .net, blazor, razor-pages, text-styling

I'm trying to add space between two strings in razor file in Blazor project.

What I'm trying to achieve is to get string like `$"{name}, {date}"`.

Its complicated because I want to set different style for {name} and {date}. So in razor file, I have something like

```
<span class="c1">@(name)</span>, <span class="c2">@(date)</span>
```

Unfortunately space between `</span>,` and `<span>` is ignored.
I also tried the following:

```
<span class="c1">@(name), </span><span class="c2">@(date)</span>
<span class="c1">@(name)</span><text>, </text><span class="c2">@(date)</span>
```

Every time I get "name,date" instead of "name, date"

I know I can achieve it by

```
@($"<span class=\"c1\">{name}</span>, <span class=\"c2\">{date}</span>")
//or
<span class="c1">@(name)@(", ")</span><span class="c2">@(date)</span>
//or
<span class="c1">@($"{name}, ")</span><span class="c2">@(date)</span>
//or maybe
<span class="c1">@name</span><span class="c2 ps-1">@(date)</span>
```

But is there any "clean" or preferred way just to not ignore the space key in such situations?

Comment: If you mean this one [<span class="c1">@(name)</span>, <span class="c2">@(date)</span>] I was expecting it will work fine. Unfortunately in Blazor razor file it is not in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try adding `&nbsp;` But generally speaking what you displayed should work. Maybe your CSS Stylesheet is messing with the spacing.

You can see your code example here, without using any stylesheet.
https://blazorfiddle.com/s/wocsxsy3

Comment: Yes :D Now I'm confused.